# Why is `-W` reserved for vendor extensions?

Tags: posix, history, options

Why does the POSIX standard [reserve the `-W` option for vendor extensions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) of the system utilities? I do not understand why the letter ‘W’ is used. ‘V’ (for **v**endor) could make more sense.

Maybe this question should be moved to Retrocomputing SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This provision was added between [Single Unix v2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/utilconv.html) (1997) and [Single Unix v3](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) (2001). It wasn't done in a vacuum: it had to take into account both the previous specifications and existing practice. If a letter was already specified for some commands, the existing commands would have to be grandfathered in and wouldn't be able to follow this guideline. If a letter was already used by popular programs not specified by POSIX or by popular implementations of POSIX programs, this would have made it harder to specify those utilities later, and harder for users to remember options with similar meanings but different letters for different commands.

Looking at the documented options in SUSv2:

```
grep -h -Po '(?<=^<dt><b>-)[[:alnum:]]' /usr/share/doc/susv2/susv2/xcu/*.html | sort | uniq -c
```

we can see that all the lowercase letters are taken by at least one utility, and most uppercase letters as well. The free letters are `-B`, `-J`, `-K`, `-Y` and `-Z`.

`-V` is taken only for two commands:

- [`command`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/command.html), where it's a variant of `-v` (added — I don't know by who originally, possibly one of the Unix specification working groups or ksh — because the original definition of `-v` wasn't quite satisfactory).
- [`dis`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/dis.html), where it's an option to print the version of the utility.

POSIX could have chosen `-V` for vendor, but it would have meant that `command` would not have followed the guidelines. This would have been annoying since `command` was created for the sake of portability (both for its behavior of avoiding differences between shell builtins and external utilities, and for its function similar to `type` but without the output formatting variability). In addition, `dis` was far from the only program out there to use `-V` for “version” (most of these weren't codified by POSIX because they weren't part of the base system: you don't need a “print version” option for a utility that's part of the base system, you just use the version number of the base system). So `-V` would have had too many exceptions, both inside POSIX and out, to be a good choice.

`-W` was only taken by [`cc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/cc.html). `cc` implementations tended to differ quite a lot between vendors (in particular, with respect to which C dialect it expected), which led to it being removed from future versions of the standard (replaced by `c89`, `c99`, etc.). Since the next version of the standard no longer had `cc`, giving `-W` a new meaning didn't exclude any standard utility. As far as I know, it wasn't a particularly common choice of option letter in non-POSIX utilities, so it was up for grabs.

Why `-W` and not another of the uppercase letters that wasn't used at all? I don't know for sure, it could have been arbitrary, but it didn't come out of the blue. The `-W` option was codified for `cc` with an argument that itself had to have a certain structure allowing multiplexing: it had to start with a character specifying what “subdomain” (compilation phase) the option applies to, followed by “subdomain-specific” options. Since POSIX.1-2001 only leaves one letter for implementation-specific options, this letter would have to be multiplexed in order to allow more than one implementation-specific behavior change. So the `-W` option of `cc` was an inspiration for how the implementation-specific `-W` could be used — not necessarily the exact syntax, but the basic principle of taking an argument with a prefix indicating a “sub-option” of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

`v` would normally be user for `version` or `verbose`, you cannot overload the switch. Bear in mind, this would be from a time when AT&T/BSD  were the only versions out there and before commercialisation. There are also other switches in use, so what is available is rather diminished.